# Authentication Oauth2 salesforce without callback url

Tags: apex, api

I want to authenticate in Salesforce with my API application in Java to do querys. The problem is that when I try to configure an application in Force with Outh I need a Callback_url but I dont have this.

Comment: You will have to give callback url. This is standard mechanism. Please explain the scenario in more detail so answerers can know the appropriate mechanism you would use.

Comment: If you don't have any callback URL then just mention any dead url for eg: example.com/nocallback.

Comment: The scenario is simple, We need to complete a PostgresSQL with salesforce data. We have did an API (java application) to retrieve this information from Force.com and persist in BBDD. In Salesforce I have created a new connected application (client id, client secret). What do you think is the best way to do the authentication? I am thinking to use this (Username - password authentication flow) https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm

Comment: I think for this Partner WSDL can be used. It contains methods for logging into salesforce and querying. [Salesforce WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps.htm)

Comment: We prefer to use REST API is more flexible than SOAP